# Android: AppCompat Snackbar and non AppCompat FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-design-library, snackbar, coordinator-layout

It's possible to use CoordinatorLayout and custom FloatingActionButton like this:

[Futuresimple - FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button)

or

[Clans - FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)

in new AppCompat Snackbar (to automatically move upward as the snackbar animates in and returns to its position when the snackbar animates out on)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use these libraries, hovewer, some built-in features are enabled only with the standard `FloatingActionButton` and the `CoordinatorLayout`.

By specifying Behaviors for child views of a CoordinatorLayout you can provide many different interactions. `FloatingActionButton` has its
[FloatingActionButton.Behavior](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.Behavior.html) and the animation in the `SnackBar` is realized by the Snackbar.Behavior which extends the [SwipeDismissBehavior](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/SwipeDismissBehavior.html).

Comment: Thank you Gabriele for explanation, can you please show me an example of use the custom Behavior with [Clans FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) for automatically moving up and down with standard AppCompat Snackbar? Or it's better to ask author for including it inside library like in the built in AppCompat FAB?

Comment: In this case I would ask the author. Or try to switch to official library.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I can't switch to official library because I use Floating action menu...